# using powershell, How do I get the first (ascending or descending) file in the list?

Tags: powershell

as above. Thanks you.

---

maybe best explained with an example.

I have the following files:

```
my-app-version-0.01.zip
my-app-version-0.04.zip
my-app-version-0.08.zip
my-app-version-0.10.zip
```

- If I want to get the first file (ascending), I would get my-app-version-0.01.zip.
- If I want to get the first file (descending), I would get my-app-version-0.10.zip.

In linux/macOS, this is what I used:

```
ls -r my-app-version*.zip | head -1
```

NOTE:

- -r is for reverse (descending sorting)
- head -1 returns the topmost result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select-object`

example:

```
Get-ChildItem my-app-version*.zip  | Select-Object -First 1
```

For desc it will be

```
Get-ChildItem my-app-version*.zip  | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: sort of related, any ideas on how to assign the full path +file name of the result to a variable?

Comment: something like this? `$var = (Get-ChildItem my-app-version*.zip  | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Fullname`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Select-Object -Last (-First) {int}`

for example:

```
$folder="C:\...."

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder  |Select-Object -First 1
```